# Bootstrap 5 Carousel Auto play and Auto pause after looping

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

I can't seem to get this carousel to do what I want. Can some one help me out? There are most likely a few things wrong here, believe me I know.

What I'd like to do with the Carousel:

On page load auto play the carousel, and once it has looped through all the slides, it auto pauses.

I can get it to play, or not rotate at all, but I can't seem to get it to play and then pause.

Please help!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
        $("#home-carousel").carousel("pause");
    });
});
```

```css
.carousel-control-prev {
  bottom: 65px;
  right: 50vw;
}
.carousel-control-next {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 65px;
}
.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: 0 0;
  border: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .15s ease;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath d='M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  left: 20vw;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
}
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  right: 20vw;
}
.carousel-indicators {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
img.img-1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 64% 60px;
  background-color: #2e3138;
}
img.img-2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 64% 60px;
  background-color: #2e3138;
}
img.img-3 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 64% 60px;
  background-color: #2e3138;
}
img.img-4 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 64% 60px;
  background-color: #2e3138;
}
img.img-5 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 64% 60px;
  background-color: #2e3138;
}
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-top: 7rem;
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active text d-flex align-items-center" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/start-a-new-fleet-icon.png" class="d-none d-md-block" style="height:40px;">Start a new fleet</button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" class="text d-flex align-items-center" aria-label="Slide 2">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/transfer-an-existing-fleet-icon.png" class="d-none d-md-block" style="height:40px;">Transfer an existing fleet</button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" class="text d-flex align-items-center" aria-label="Slide 3">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/electric-bolt-icon.png" class="d-none d-md-block" style="height:40px;">Electrify your fleet</button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" class="text d-flex align-items-center" aria-label="Slide 4">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/car-key-icon.png" class="d-none d-md-block" style="height:40px;">Get a Novated lease</button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://s3-alpha.figma.com/hub/file/948140848/1f4d8ea7-e9d9-48b7-b70c-819482fb10fb-cover.png" class="img-1 w-100 d-block" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h5 class="carousel-header"><span class="text-red">Start</span><span class="text-caps"> a new fleet</span></h5>
        <p class="carousel-txt">
            A getting started guide<br><br>
            <a class="btn btn-bd-light" href="#" role="button">Find out more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://s3-alpha.figma.com/hub/file/948140848/1f4d8ea7-e9d9-48b7-b70c-819482fb10fb-cover.png" class="img-2 w-100 d-block" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h5 class="carousel-header"><span class="text-red">Transfer</span><span class="text-caps"> an existing fleet</span></h5>
        <p class="carousel-txt">
            Bring your current fleet over to Custom Fleet!<br><br>
            <a class="btn btn-bd-light" href="#" role="button">Get started</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://s3-alpha.figma.com/hub/file/948140848/1f4d8ea7-e9d9-48b7-b70c-819482fb10fb-cover.png" class="img-3 w-100 d-block" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h5 class="carousel-header"><span class="text-green">Electrify</span><span class="text-caps"> your fleet</span></h5>
        <p class="carousel-txt">
            The future of fleet is not the internal combustion engine – it's electric<br><br>
            <a class="btn btn-bd-green" href="#" role="button">Contact us</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://s3-alpha.figma.com/hub/file/948140848/1f4d8ea7-e9d9-48b7-b70c-819482fb10fb-cover.png" class="img-4 w-100 d-block" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h5 class="carousel-header"><span class="text-caps">Get a </span><span class="text-red">Novated lease</span></h5>
        <p class="carousel-txt">
            Get your dream car and save a bundle<br><br>
            <a class="btn btn-bd-light" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
     <button class="carousel-control-prev d-block d-md-none" type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next d-block d-md-none" type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your actual attempts, please, or specifically highlight which parts of the shown code they are supposed to be?

Comment: I attempted some JS to call the carousel to pause on slid, but it only pauses after one slide passes. I want it to stop once it reaches the last slide.

Comment: The Event object that will get passed to your handler function has several additional properties, using those you should be able to figure out whether the event occurred on the last slide or not. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/#events

Answer (score 0):

With this, you might have to write some javascript for it. Or initialise it with java script.

You can Create the carousel and use the > .ride class to make it loop throught on page load.

Use javascript and bootstrap data-configt to give it the pause attribute.

> "As of Bootstrap 5.2.0, all components support an experimental
> reserved data attribute data-bs-config that can house simple component
> configuration as a JSON string. When an element has
> data-bs-config='{"delay":0,"

You can try replacing that with pause : true.

This is a example of the logic:

Bootstrap carousel load on page load with .ride > When last slide reached > Check its reached last slide. > add pause data-config to it
[Bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/#via-data-attributes)

It is worth reading the bottom of the bootstrap page get an understanding of the available configurations.